# Covariant return type and type conversion

Tags: c++, covariance, dynamic-dispatch

`s->duplicate()` returns an object of type `Box*`, but I'm getting an error initializing it with `Box*`. It looks like it's being converted back to `Shape*`. What is the point of having covariant return types if it's converted back to the base class pointer?:

```
struct Shape
{
    virtual Shape* duplicate()
    {
        return new Shape;
    }
};

struct Box : Shape
{
    virtual Box* duplicate()
    {
        return new Box;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Shape* s = new Box;
    Box*   b = s->duplicate();
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:22:12: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'Box *' with an rvalue of type 'Shape *'
    Box*   b = s->duplicate();
           ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although `Box::duplicate` *is* being invoked at runtime (via virtual dispatch), and although `Box::duplicate` *does* override `Shape::duplicate` (covariantly), and although `Box::duplicate` *does* return a `Box*`, you'll still get a `Shape*` pointer because you are calling `duplicate()` through a `Shape*` pointer, and `Shape*` is the return type of `Shape::duplicate()`, and the compiler only sees you calling `Shape::duplicate`, not `Box::duplicate`.

C++ is not able to dynamically select types, so this is the best it can do. Your `Box*` is being automatically converted to a `Shape*` on the way out of `Box::duplicate`. As Barry said, "it still has to compile at compile time, and at compile time all we know is that it returns a `Shape*`".

Then, to make it into a `Box*` again, you need to explicitly cast it (using `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`) because no implicit down-conversion exists.

> `[C++11: 10.3/7]:` **The return type of an overriding function shall be** either identical to the return type of the overridden function or **covariant with the classes of the functions**. *[..]*
>
> `[C++11: 10.3/8]:` If the return type of `D::f` differs from the return type of `B::f`, the class type in the return type of `D::f` shall
>   be complete at the point of declaration of `D::f` or shall be the class type `D`. **When the overriding function is called as the final overrider of the overridden function, its result is converted to the type returned by the (statically chosen) overridden function** (5.2.2). *[..]*

In the standard text, a pertinent example follows.

Comment: They really couldn't have come up with a shorter example to illustrate this section?

Comment: @Barry: Surprised? :P

Comment: @Kad: Not sure what you're trying to say. Did you mean to ask some question about that line of code? That is invalid because it's an attempted implicit base-to-derived conversion, which is not permitted (and I actually said this in the answer). Try `Shape* s = new Box();` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The point isn't to do this:

```
Box*   b = s->duplicate();
```

That obviously can't work since `Shape::duplicate()` returns a `Shape*`. The point, rather, is to accept a `Box*` if you're calling `duplicate()` on a `Box` directly:

```
Box* old = new Box;
Box* b = old->duplicate(); // OK! We know it's a Box
```

Comment: Since the dispatch is performed at runtime why isn't the return type obtained from `Box::duplicate()`?

Comment: @templateboy Because it still has to compile at compile time, and at compile time all we know is that it returns a `Shape*`.

Comment: The solution isn't very generic. What if I don't know what `duplicate()` returns?

Comment: @templateboy You know it returns a `Shape*`. And if you know that `Box::duplicate()` returns a `Box*`, then you can use that info? I don't understand what you're getting at.